# JQuery slide is not smooth

Tags: jquery

Using exactly the same code as this - http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/10/.

I have a vertical menu inside the slide div and here are the issues.

1. Every time a link is clicked in the menu, the slide collapses. So, if user has to open another page, he has to click on the div to expand it again.
2. After a link is clicked, the slide collapses half way, then the target page loads with a flash and then the collapse continues. So the slide collapse is very jerky.

I think, the first problem can be solved by having a lil button (at top ) on the menu to open or close the slide, instead of the current 'click function'. But the disadvantage would be, user has to move his cursor to the top to collapse it. I am unable to decide, what would be the best.

...And I have no clue about the second.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slide">
   Vertical menu here
</div>
<div style="width:350px; background:#ccc;">
     Pages load here
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slide {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    top:10px;
    left:-280px;
    background-color:#8cc;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var r=0, dir=true;
    $(".slide").click(function() {
        dir = !dir;
        r = dir? -280 : 0;
        $(this).stop().animate({left: r+'px'}, 800);
    });
});
```

Comment: it is very smooth to me on your fiddle, what's within your slide menu? If you want smoother animations, do consider using css3 transitions, those are hardware accelerated

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: It works very well already for me too.  I believe a problem is that jQuery animations are not hardware accelerated on all devices (as gary said) so they can be very laggy on cheaper systems and mobile.  I recommend http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ for stuff like this.  It does CSS animations in jQuery syntax and they're super smooth.

Comment: The fiddle is working fine, because there are no page loads and vertical menu. I put the reason for the jerky animation in the question.

Comment: use css transitions instead. http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/DcWS2/597/

Comment: You want open the menu when click on the menu, and click outside will close the menu ?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the collapse of slide on link click by adding stopPropagation()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var r=0, dir=true;
    $(".slide").click(function() {
        dir = !dir;
        r = dir? -280 : 0;
        $(this).stop().animate({left: r+'px'}, 500);
    });
    $(".slide a").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/Y4bLA/

**EDIT**

Adding feature to close the menu on clicking outside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var r=-280, dir=true;
    $(".slide").click(function(e) {
        dir = !dir;
        r = dir? -280 : 0;
        $(this).stop().animate({left: r+'px'}, 500);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".slide a").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        console.log(r);
        if(r==0)$(".slide").click();
    });
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/Y4bLA/1/

Comment: That was great. Is there anything like, to collapse the div when clicked anywhere outside it.

Comment: The menu's still collapsing after link clicks

Comment: Not happening for me in chrome browser.. which browser are you using? Pleas try the fiddle

Comment: Check this final fiddle. It has the click outside close feature http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/Y4bLA/1/

Comment: the slide is in a master. The pages load inside an iframe that is also in the same master. Is this the reason, why there is a flash and the collapse

Comment: So you are telling your menu is still collapsing on clicking the link, even after having stopPropagation? I dont think opening a link inside iframe has a ny difference

Comment: Yes exactly. There is a page load flash on every click and this div collapses...Maybe I should stick to having a button for open/close.right. What should I do to have the div expanded at first page load

Comment: If the page holding this html is reloading, then it will collapse, since its a fresh page load. you might need other implementations like cookies to remember the menu state

Comment: You are right. This menu is in the Master which loads always and so the collapse. Guess have to live with that.Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to **stop click  event from bublling** of links in slide  use e.stopPropagation();`

See this [Lab Demo](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/HakQolVvnsj4pQP7gRNiYa7LSNY0Iv0t)

**Add this to you code**

```
$(".slide a").click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();


 });
```

Comment: With return false, pages dont open. Otherwise they do, but the menu still collapses

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @Ruby Updated my Answer. Sorry for misunderstanding your Question

Comment: @SajithNair: Sorry But I did'nt notice your fiddle I wanted to provide a demo

Answer (score 1):

This code will open when click inside menu, close when click outside menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/599/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide").click(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({left: '0px'}, 800);
    });

    $('html').click(function (e) {
        if ( !($('.slide').has(e.target).length || 
            $('.slide').is(e.target)
        ) ) {
            $('.slide').stop().animate({left: '-280px'}, 800);
        }
    });
});
```